# Update JTable Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem. I am developing an application that manage elements of a database table called Person.

In the first window, I show all rows of the table in a `JTable`. I have a button for insert new persons in the table. The button open a new window where I can introduce the fields. My problem is that when I insert the element, I don't know how update the table with the new register.

In the main window, i have a method called `rellenaTabla`, that fills the table when I create the window:

```
public void rellenaTabla(){
ArrayList<Persona> lista = new ArrayList<Persona>();
lista = po1.listaDePersonas();


for (Persona persona: lista){
    Object obj[] = {persona.getIdPersona(), persona.getNombrePersona(), 
    persona.getEdadPersona(), persona.getProfesionPersona(), persona.getTelefonoPersona()};
    m = (DefaultTableModel)tabla.getModel();
    m.addRow(obj);

}

tabla.setModel(m);   
}
```

This works when I create the window, but if I call this method when I insert a new register in the table, the `JTable` doesn't change. I have to close the main window and open again to show the changes.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you know the code is invoked? Do you have any display statements inside the loop to make sure there is data in the ArrayList? If there is data in the ArrayList, then the code looks reasonable. Also there is no need to reset the model. You are adding data directly to the model of the table.

Comment: Also a better solution might be to create a custom TableModel to contain `Persona` objects. Then you can treat each row of data as a `Persona`. Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step approach on how to do this. You should only use this approach once you solve your current problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.